# How to plot some variables of a dataframe against some others?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The function pairs() produces p scatter plot of all the p x p pairs of variables.

```
    x<-rnorm(100,0,1)
    y<-rnorm(100,0,1)
    z<-rnorm(100,1,1)
    t<-rnorm(100,2,10)
    dd<-cbind(x,y,z,t)
    pairs(dd)
```

But I would like to be able to choose the ones for the 'lines' and columns of the grid. For instance plot these pairs (x,y) (x,z) (t,y) (t,z). Is there a function that accepts a formula like (x+t)~(z+y) for instance ?

Comment: `pairs(dd, horInd=c(1, 4), verInd=c(2,3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the specific arguments of `pairs` or create a custom function that accepts a formula as input:

```
pairs(dd, horInd=c(1, 4), verInd=c(2,3))
```

Custom function:

```
my_pairs <- function(df, formula) {
  form <- deparse(formula)
  s <- strsplit(form, "~")
  lhs <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(s[[1]][1], "\\+")))
  rhs <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(s[[1]][2], "\\+")))

  lhs.ind <- match(lhs, colnames(df))
  rhs.ind <- match(rhs, colnames(df))
  all_cmbs <- expand.grid(lhs.ind, rhs.ind)
  rows <- all_cmbs[,1]
  cols <- all_cmbs[,2]
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  for(i in 1:4) {
    eval(substitute(plot(df[,rows[i]], df[,cols[i]], 
                         xlab=colnames(df)[rows[i]],
                         ylab=colnames(df)[cols[i]])))
  }
}

my_pairs(dd, x + t ~ y + z)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Pierre. I'm so ashamed I didn't see these arguments in the help page. (merci beaucoup, si ton nom révèle bien que tu es français). I just need to see for the axis names and details like this. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Edit : it seems 3.1.1 version of R does not include these arguments. So on my computer I found the arguments in help but not on my colleague computer. Just adding this for those who wouldn't find the arguments.